# Android Studio 3.3 Canary 6 - android.enableJetifier=true doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

If we create a new project with latest Android Studio 3.3 Canary 6 it Androidx support by default.

But the problem is I'm unable to use almost any third party libraries because of the import conflict.

Libraries uses

`android.support.v7.app.*`

While androidx uses `androidx.*`

I think setting `android.enableJetifier=true` is supposed to resolve this issue by Automatically converting third-party libraries to use Androidx but it doesn't work at all and it clearly shows message saying

> cannot resolve `android.support.v7.app.whatever`

I know third party libraries needs to be refactored to `androidx` but it will take some time of course for them all to be refactored to Androix. In the meanwhile is there any possible solution for this problem?

Some issues regarding this

[RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle/issues/269)

[Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/664)

Comment: Any news regarding this issue?

Comment: Neh man, for now I'm not migrating to the androidx because compatibility issue of a lot of libraries